# How does one fix a "Variable not in scope" error?

Tags: haskell, lambda, ghci

Can you please help me understand the error and how to fix it?

```
comp = \x -> f(g(h(x)))
```

The error is

> "Variable not in scope: f :: t0 -> t2"

for `f, g` and `h`, which they are just some functions not otherwise specified.

Comment: What do you expect `f`, `g`, and `h` to refer to there?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica they are just some functions not otherwise specified. Does the problem lie with exactly that lack of specification?

Comment: Yes, it does. You can't use variables without Haskell knowing where to get their values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're trying to build a function that composes 3 functions, much like how `.` composes 2 functions. To do that, you can't just make up names in the body and expect GHC to know what you meant by them. Instead, you need to bring them into scope somehow, like this: `comp f g h = \x -> f(g(h(x)))`